# Why can't I assign an Employee instance to ArrayList<? super Manager>?

Tags: java

Given that `Manager extends Employee`

I was surprised to get a compiler error when I try to add an Employee to an ArrayList of Managers,

```
   ArrayList<? super Manager> sonsOfEmployee = new ArrayList<>();
    sonsOfEmployee.add(new Employee("Manager",100000));
```

I get error

`Required type: capture of ? super Manager`

Comment: `ArrayList<? super Manager> sonsOfEmployee = new ArrayList<Manager>();` compiles.  If `Manger` is a _subtype_ of `Employee`, then it would make sense that you can't add an `Employee` to a `List<Manager>`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Please look at the question carefully. it is not a List<Manager>

Comment: I did look at the question carefully.  An `ArrayList<? super Manager>` _could_ be an `ArrayList<Manager>` as far as Java is concerned, and that's why it's not allowing this assignment.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so why can't we add an `Employee` to `ArrayList<Manager>`? After all it fits the rule we have set: `? super Manager` is allowed.

Comment: No.  `List<? super Manager>` does not mean what you think it means, you have it backwards.  `List<? super Manager>` means that it's a `List<T>` for some _fixed but unknown_ type `T` that is `Manager` or one of its supertypes.  It is _not_ a `List` containing anything that is a supertype of `Manager`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman To me, your two statements here are equivalent I can't see how they are different. {Louis] "1) a List<T> for some fixed but unknown type T that is Manager or one of its supertypes. ....2) a List containing anything that is a supertype of Manager"

Comment: You'll need to think harder about my first comment, then.  What would you expect to happen with the following code: `List<Manager> managerList = new ArrayList<>();  List<? super Manager> superManagerList = managerList;  superManagerList.add(new Employee("Manager", 100000));  System.out.println(managerList);`  If this code worked, you would have an `Employee` in a `managerList`, which is impossible.

Comment: @LouisWasserman But there are other generics code examples that also show ridiculous output involving String and Number ArrayLists and yet they compile fine.

Comment: You're welcome to ask questions about those, then, but the code example I gave in my last comment is the reason this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lower-bounded** generic collections (`Collection<? super A>`) are **writable** - that's correct.

First, let's examine what type of collection we can assign to it.

`List<? super Manager>` means that you can assign to this list a list of managers, a list of employees, a list of objects. All these assignments are perfectly valid and all of them will compile:

```
List<? super Manager> list;
list = new ArrayList<Manager>();
list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

That means that under the hood of `list` can appear any of these lists. We know for sure only that could be a list of type `Manager` or its super-types. And if it will be an `ArrayList<Manager>` you can't put an `Employee` object into this collection.

We can put an instance of `Manager` into the `Collections<Employee>` but not the other way around.

Let's consider *another example*:

```
ArrayList<? super String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add((CharSequence) "Java"); // that will not compile
    
ArrayList<? super CharSequence> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("Java");
```

Adding an object of type `CharSequence` to the `ArrayList<? super String>` will fail to compile because the interface `CharSequence` is a super-type of `String`.

But we can add a string to `ArrayList<? super CharSequence>` because `String` is compatible with `CharSequence` type.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence - it is not an Arraylist<Manager>. It is an ArrayLis that contains suprttype of Manager... which is Employee. You said, "nd if it will be an ArrayList<Manager> you can't put an Employee object into this collection."

Comment: Isn't Charsequence following the rule by being a supertype of String? [Alexander] "Adding an object of type CharSequence to the ArrayList<? super String> will fail to compile because the interface CharSequence is a super-type of String."

Comment: @likejudo You misunderstand. `ArrayList<? super String>` **isn't an actual type**. In plain words, generics provide a way to tell the compiler that type we don't know what the type is.  `<T>` and *wild cards* are not the real types.  `ArrayList<? super String>` exist only in the source code. All generic information will be replaced with type casting. That process is called [generic erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

Comment: @likejudo  At runtime, we will have an `ArrayList<Manager>` or `ArrayList<String>` (technically an `ArrayList` that maintains `Object[]` which elements will be casted into `String` or `Manager` type when we call `get()` on this collection).

Comment: Following the PECS rule,`ArrayList<? super String>` even if I add an instance of a supertype of String, it will fail?

Comment: @likejudo Please reread my two previous comments. You are confusing the **type of the reference** (like `ArrayList<? super String>`) and the actual **type of the object** (which can be `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Object>`). Now forget about generics for a second and answer the *question:* can you add an instance of `Object` to the `ArrayList<String>`? The answer is **no**, right? For the same reason you can't add an instance of `Object` to `ArrayList<? super String>`, a **real collection** which is under the hood of this wild-card reference could be `ArrayList<String>`. Is it clear now?